# Extensible relational division in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, relational-division

In this example class `IcdPatient` represents a many-to-many relationship between a Patient table (not shown in this example) and a lookup table `Icd`.

```
public class IcdPatient
    {
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public int ConditionCode { get; set; }

        public static List<IcdPatient> GetIcdPatientList()
        {
            return new List<IcdPatient>()
            {
                new IcdPatient { PatientId = 100, ConditionCode = 111 },
                new IcdPatient { PatientId = 100, ConditionCode = 222 },
                new IcdPatient { PatientId = 200, ConditionCode = 111 },
                new IcdPatient { PatientId = 200, ConditionCode = 222 },
                new IcdPatient { PatientId = 3, ConditionCode = 222 },
            };
        }
    }
    public class Icd
    {
        public int ConditionCode { get; set; }
        public string ConditionName { get; set; }

        public static List<Icd> GetIcdList()
        {
            return new List<Icd>()
            {
                new Icd() { ConditionCode =111, ConditionName ="Condition 1"},
                new Icd() { ConditionCode =222, ConditionName ="Condition 2"},
            };
        }
    }
```

I would like for the user to be able to enter as many conditions as they want, and get a LINQ object back that tells them how many `PatientId`s satisfy that query.  I've come up with:

```
List<string> stringFilteredList = new List<string> { "Condition 1", "Condition 2" };
            List<int> filteringList = new List<int> { 111,222 };
            var manyToMany = IcdPatient.GetIcdPatientList();
            var icdList = Icd.GetIcdList();
            /*Working method without joining on the lookup table*/
            var grouped = from m in manyToMany
                          group m by m.PatientId into g
                          where g.Count() == filteringList.Distinct().Count()
                          select new
                          {
                              PatientId = g.Key,
                              Count = g.Count()
                          };
            /*End*/
            foreach (var item in grouped)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.PatientId);
            }
```

Let's say that `IcdPatient` has a composite primary key on both fields, so we know that each row is unique.  If we find the distinct number of entries in `filteringList` and do a count on the number of times a `PatientId` shows up, that means we've found all the people who have all conditions.  Because the codes can be esoteric, I would like to do something like
let the user table in the `ConditionName` in type Icd and perform the same operation.  I've not used LINQ this way a lot and I've gathered:

```
 List<int> filteringList = new List<int> { 111,222 };
            List<string> stringFilteredList= new List<string>{"Condition 1","Condition 2" };
            filteringList.Distinct();
            var manyToMany = IcdPatient.GetIcdPatientList();
            var icdList = Icd.GetIcdList();
            /*Working method without joining on the lookup table*/
            var grouped = from m in manyToMany
                          join i in icdList on 
                          m.ConditionCode equals i.ConditionCode
                          //group m by m.PatientId into g
                          group new {m,i} by new { m.ConditionCode }into g
                          where g.Count() == filteringList.Distinct().Count()
                          select new
                          {

                              Condition = g.Key.ConditionCode

                          };
            /*End*/
```

but can't get anything to work.  This is essentially a join on top of my first query, but I'm not getting what I need to group on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group anything in this case, just use a join and a contains:

```
List<string> stringFilteredList= new List<string>{"Condition 1","Condition 2" };

var patients = 
    from icd in Icd.GetIcdList()
    join patient in IcdPatient.GetIcdPatientList() on icd.ConditionCode equals patient.ConditionCode
    where stringFilteredList.Contains(icd.ConditionName)
    select patient.PatientId;
```

Comment: This doesn't work because PatientId3 only has Condition2, and not condition one.  This query is satisfied only when we get all patient IDs who have all conditions in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say that IcdPatient has a composite primary key on both fields, so we know that each row is unique. If we find the distinct number of entries in filteringList and do a count on the number of times a PatientId shows up, that means we've found all the people who have all conditions. Because the codes can be esoteric, I would like to do something like let the user table in the ConditionName in type Icd and perform the same operation.

I believe you're asking:

> Given a list of `ConditionCode`s, return a list of `PatientId`s where every patient has every condition in the list.

In that case, the easiest thing to do is group your IcdPatients table by Id, so that we can tell every condition that a patient has by looking once. Then we check that every `ConditionCode` we're looking for is in the group. In code, that looks like:

```
var result = IcdPatient.GetIcdPatientList()
                    // group up all the objects with the same PatientId
                    .GroupBy(patient => patient.PatientId)
                    // gather the information we care about into a single object of type {int, List<int>}
                    .Select(patients => new {Id = patients.Key,
                                            Conditions = patients.Select(p => p.ConditionCode)})
                    // get rid of the patients without every condition
                    .Where(conditionsByPatient =>
                            conditionsByPatient.Conditions.All(condition => filteringList.Contains(condition)))
                    .Select(conditionsByPatient => conditionsByPatient.Id);
```

In query format, that looks like:

```
var groupedInfo = from patient in IcdPatient.GetIcdPatientList()
                  group patient by patient.PatientId
                    into patients
                    select new { Id = patients.Key,
                                 Conditions = patients.Select(patient => patient.ConditionCode) };
var resultAlt = from g in groupedInfo
                where g.Conditions.All(condition => filteringList.Contains(condition))
                select g.Id;
```

---

Edit: If you'd also like to let your user specify the `ConditionName` rather than the `ConditionId` then simply convert from one to the other, storing the result in `filteringList`, like so:

```
var conditionNames = // some list of names from the user
var filteringList = Icd.GetIcdList().Where(icd => conditionNames.Contains(icd.ConditionName))
                                    .Select(icd => icd.ConditionCode);
```